# Django 1.5 - adding base class for models and views

Tags: python, django, radix

I am trying to add base class for my all models defined in different apps. I created a package as `lib/base.py`:

```
from django.db import models
import logging

# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Base(models.Model):

class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now in different home apps directory, I would like to use this base model:

```
from django.db import models
from libs.base import Base
# Create your models here.
class Home(Base):
    msg = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, msg):
        home = cls(msg=msg)
        # do something with the book
        return home
```

when I run the server, I get following error:

```
 File "/Users/.../home/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from libs.base import Base
ImportError: No module named libs.base
```

I cannot find what I am missing here?

Comment: Wait a sec, I hope, your `lib/base.py` is not equal to your listing? Cause if `ModelBase` is an empty class, you should use `pass`

Comment: Correction: I update base class name to following:

Comment: from django.db import models
import logging

# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Base(models.Model):

class Meta:
        abstract = True

Comment: If there is realy no code relating to `Base` class, you should append a line `pass` after `class ModelBase(models.Model):`

Comment: In other words, I think `lib/base.py` has a wrong syntax. Try to execute `base.py` by python

Comment: You say you created the file `lib/base.py`, but in your code you are importing it as `libs.base`. Is that a typo?

Comment: I yes, it was typo. I fixed the problem. Looks like I had to add project name to my import syntax "from myproject.libs.base import Base". But now that I try to access logger object from based class, it returns me error.

Answer (score 0):

You should append your `libs` module to installed apps of your project:

`settings.py:`

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'home',
    ...
    'libs', # Add this!
)
...
```

Comment: Try to remove all `__pycache__` directories in project